# copying data structure and data results in duplicate columns

Tags: r

Consider this example:

```
#set seed to 1 and create 2 data vectors
set.seed(1)
x1<-rnorm(10)
x2<-rnorm(10)
#place the data in a data frame
d<-data.frame(x1=x1,x2=x2)
#create a new data vector by scaling the first data vector
d$x1s <- scale(x1)
#Create a new, empty dataset with the same structure as d, but only 2 columns
newd<-d[0,c(2,3)]
#Copy the data
newd[1:NROW(d),] <- d[,c(2,3)]
```

The result is

```
newd
            x2       x1s.1       x1s.2
1   1.51178117 -0.97190653 -0.97190653
2   0.38984324  0.06589991  0.06589991
3  -0.62124058 -1.23987805 -1.23987805
4  -2.21469989  1.87433300  1.87433300
5   1.12493092  0.25276523  0.25276523
6  -0.04493361 -1.22045645 -1.22045645
7  -0.01619026  0.45507643  0.45507643
8   0.94383621  0.77649606  0.77649606
9   0.82122120  0.56826358  0.56826358
10  0.59390132 -0.56059319 -0.56059319
```

Why does it create a third column that is the same as the second one? How can I avoid that?

Comment: Have you tried `newd<- d[,c(2,3)]`?

Comment: @Duck Just now and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the structure of `scale` output which returns a `matrix`

```
str(scale(x1))
# num [1:10, 1] -0.9719 0.0659 -1.2399 1.8743 0.2528 ...  # // matrix
# - attr(*, "scaled:center")= num 0.132
# - attr(*, "scaled:scale")= num 0.781
```

It is mentioned in `?scale`

> For scale.default, the centered, scaled matrix. The numeric centering and scalings used (if any) are returned as attributes "scaled:center" and "scaled:scale"

and thus we have the 'x1s' as. `matrix` column.  If we need to change it, then remove the `dim` attributes by converting to `vector` with `as.vector` and assign it to 'x1s'

```
d$x1s <- as.vector(scale(x1))
```

Now, if we create the empty dataset, the 'x1s' is a normal column

```
newd <- d[0,c(2,3)]
str(newd)
#'data.frame':  0 obs. of  2 variables:
#$ x2 : num 
#$ x1s: num
```

as opposed to the structure of the empty column in OP's code

```
str(newd)
#'data.frame':  0 obs. of  2 variables:
#$ x2 : num 
#$ x1s: num[0 , 1] # // matrix column
```

Comment: I am trying to write a function that takes as input whatever the user provides as input, be it `scale(x1)` or `as.vector(scale(x1))`. Is there a way to fix the dimension of `x1s` in `newd` i.e. make it a vector instead of a matrix?

Comment: @papgeo apply `as.vector` on a vector or matrix returns `vector`.  So, the code in the solution should work for you.  If you want to do a check.  You can use a check within the function `is.matrix` and then apply `as.vector`, but in any case this should work

Comment: @papgeo my intention to write this as an answer was based on your question `Why does it create a third column that is the same as the second one?`

Comment: I will accept the answer. Just to clarify though: when you say to apply `as.vector` do you mean in a loop. So right after `newd<-d[0,c(2,3)]`, type `for (j in 1:dim(newd)[2])
    newd[,j]<-as.vector(newd[,j])  `?

Comment: @papgeo Actually you don't need to initialize a 0 row object.  As in the comments from Duck, you could direclty copy the required rows/columns from the other object and create that.  I didn't meant a loop.  It is just the same code as yours except how you assign the `scale`

Comment: @papgeo Are you using a loop in the actual use case?  From the example showed, it is not required

Comment: I need `newd` to have the same structure as `d`. This is in case `d` includes categorical data. If the structure in `d` is lost, then in `newd` we will not know which is categorical and which is numerical data. That is why I am using the 0 row object. About "how you assign the scale": what if I don't know how the scale was assigned? The only answer I can think of is the above loop.

Comment: @papgeo I would then apply `as.vector(` on the output you receive whether it is `scale`d or not.  I assumed that you won't recieve a `data.frame` or `data.table`